# how to handle Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading

Tags: javascript, html

I want to handle Uncaught (in promise):

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading) this error in javascript. I want to alert if this type of error occurs....

How to do this in javascirpt ??

```
         if(typeof( dataName) === undefined)
                {
                    alert("undefined")
                }
```

[image]

Comment: put some code and ss of output

Comment: did you want to handle the error (.catch), or find the cause of the error (post some code), or prevent the error (check your variables)?

Comment: Does the posted code relate to the question?

Comment: `typeof` returns a string and not `undefined` so it is either `dataName === undefined`  or `typeof( dataName) === 'undefined')`  to check if `dataName` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that your `getProduct` function is `async` and that you try to access the property `english_name` for a variable that is `undefined`.

So if you want to handle that error you need to handle the error case for the promise chain at some point. Or ensure that the error does not happen at all:

```js
async function getProduct() {
  let dataName = undefined;
  
  dataName.english_name = 1;
}


getProduct().catch(err => {
  console.error('error occured: ',err.message)
});
```

or

```js
async function getProduct() {
  let dataName = undefined;

  dataName.english_name = 1;
}

async function run() {
  try {
    await getProduct();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('error occured: ', err.message)
  }
}

run();
```

`typeof` returns a string and not `undefined` so it is either `dataName === undefined`  or `typeof( dataName) === 'undefined')`  to check if `dataName` is `undefined`:

```js
async function getProduct() {
  let dataName = undefined;
  if (typeof(dataName) !== 'undefined') {
    dataName.english_name = 1;
  }

  if (dataName !== undefined) {
    dataName.english_name = 1;
  }
}

async function run() {
  try {
    await getProduct();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('error occured: ', err.message)
  }
}

run();
```